# How to get root privilege in Docker container?

Tags: macos, jenkins, docker

These are my operations:

1. docker cp /my/path/.git mycontainer:/my/path/.git

then I found something wrong, so I want to rm the folder

2. docker exec -t -i mycontainer /bin/bash
3. rm -Rf /my/path/.git

And I got **Permission Denied**

[image]

**Additional:**

How can I copy(initial) my .git to jenkins git repository manually. Too slow to fetch from remote repository.

Comment: what image are you using? Probably the base image dockerfile lets you connect with a specific user without SU privs

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins/
jenkins's official image @YaronIdan

Comment: Are you able to see the copied files?

Comment: Can you use mount using -V option?

Comment: I run the container with -v option and I can only see it in container. I have post a solution. Anyway thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://forums.docker.com/t/host-path-of-volume/12277/7

Thanks to **aleveille** for his great answer!

```
$ docker volume ls

$ screen  ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/tty

$ ls -ltrh /var/lib/docker/volumes
```

Comment: You should accept the answer if it answers your question, regardless if it's your own - so that others know that it's solved.